# jQuery Remove Item On Button Click

Tags: jquery

I simply want to remove these items on button click, and I'm having trouble. I've had a look at other similar posts too, but I'm not familiar with jQuery so I'm still having trouble.

I want to be able to delete individual items on button click.

Thanks! :)

jQuery:

```
$("#cart_remove").click(function() {
    $("#cart_remove").parent("#cart_g_id").html();
});
```

HTML:

```
<tr id="cart_g_id"> 
     <td>
         <a id="cart_remove">Remove</a>
     </td>
</tr>
// I have multiple items here
```

Comment: use `$("#cart_remove").on('click',function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});`

Comment: Tried it, it didn't work

Comment: see console what error it throws

Comment: It's showing no error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change button id to class in your code just because of you are having a multiple button

```
  HTML :
        <table>
          <tr class="temp1"> 
             <td>
                <a class="cart_remove">Remove1</a>
             </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="temp2">
             <td>
              <a class="cart_remove">Remove2</a>
             </td>
         </tr>
       </table>

 jQUERY:  

   $( document ).ready(function() {
     $(".cart_remove").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
   });
```

});

try this i hope it help to you

Comment: please check it on jsfiddle link where i have make some little bit changes in my code and it's working fine link is "https://jsfiddle.net/edfy4Lyh/"

i hope its working fine now as per your requirement

Comment: I got the link working, the code works fine in JSFiddle but for some reason it  doesn't work in my code

Comment: please check it out have you add jquery file in your code or not